# Equality with binomials

Tags: co.combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I am reading a paper and I am trying to understand an equality which is given without proof:
$$\sum_{k=1}^s\binom{2s-k}{s}\frac{k}{2s-k}v^k(v-1)^{s-k}=v\sum_{k=0}^{s-1}\binom{2s}{k}\frac{s-k}{s}(v-1)^{k} $$
Here, $s>0$, $k$ and $v$ are positive integers.
The equality in question appears in Lemma 2.1 of
http://web.williams.edu/Mathematics/sjmiller/public_html/ntharm15/handouts/graphs/mckay_EigenvalueLargeRandomGraphs.pdf

Would you be kind and give me some insights on how to derive this equality?

Thank you,

LH

Comment: I added a non-automated proof below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a non-automated proof. We divide by $v$, and then we expand $v^{k-1}$ on the left hand side as
$$v^{k-1}=(1+v-1)^{k-1}=\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\binom{k-1}{j}(v-1)^j.$$
Then, looking at the coefficients of $v-1$ on the two sides, we are left with proving the identity
$$ \sum_{\substack{0\leq k\leq s\\0\leq j\leq k-1\\j+s-k=\ell}}\binom{2s-k}{s}\frac{k}{2s-k}\binom{k-1}{j} = \binom{2s}{\ell}\frac{s-\ell}{s},\qquad 0\leq\ell\leq s-1.$$
With the notation $m:=s-k$ we have $k=s-m$, $j=\ell-m$, and the identity becomes
$$ \sum_{m=0}^\ell\binom{s+m}{s}\frac{s-m}{s+m}\binom{s-m-1}{\ell-m} = \binom{2s}{\ell}\frac{s-\ell}{s},\qquad 0\leq\ell\leq s-1.$$
Equivalently,
$$ \sum_{m=0}^\ell\binom{s+m-1}{s-1}\binom{s-m}{\ell-m} = \binom{2s}{\ell},\qquad 0\leq\ell\leq s-1, \tag3$$
i.e.,
$$ \sum_{m=0}^\ell\binom{s+m-1}{s-1}\binom{s-m}{s-\ell} = \binom{2s}{2s-\ell},\qquad 0\leq\ell\leq s-1.$$
We derive this one from the obvious identity of analytic functions
$$ (1-x)^{-s}(1-x)^{\ell-s-1}=(1-x)^{\ell-2s-1},\qquad |x|<1.$$
Indeed, expanding each factor as a power series around the origin, we find that:

- the coefficient of $x^m$ in $(1-x)^{-s}$ equals $\binom{s+m-1}{s-1}$;
- the coefficient of $x^{\ell-m}$ in $(1-x)^{\ell-s-1}$ equals $\binom{s-m}{s-\ell}$;
- the coefficient of $x^{\ell}$ in $(1-x)^{\ell-2s-1}$ equals $\binom{2s}{2s-\ell}$.

Comment: The identity in (3) is valid due to Vandermonde-Chu's identity.

Comment: @T.Amdeberhan: Thank you, I am not familiar with this subject. At any rate, I gave a quick proof of (3) as well.

Comment: That is the kind of elementary proof that I would like to have. Thanks

Answer (score 13):

Let's re-index the sum on the LHS of the problem (for the below convenience) so that
$$\frac1s\sum_{k=0}^{s-1}\binom{s+k-1}k(s-k)v^{s-k}(v-1)^k
=\frac{v}s\sum_{k=0}^{s-1}\binom{2s}k(s-k)(v-1)^k.$$
Or, just pull out the $v$ factor (leaving behind $\frac1s$, again for convenience):
$$\frac1s\sum_{k=0}^{s-1}\binom{s+k-1}k(s-k)v^{s-1-k}(v-1)^k
=\frac1s\sum_{k=0}^{s-1}\binom{2s}k(s-k)(v-1)^k.\tag1$$

We apply an automated technique called the [Wilf-Zeilberger method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilf%E2%80%93Zeilberger_pair) for which Zeilberger wrote an algorithm, now implemented in symbolic softwares such as *Maple* and *Mathematica*.

To prove the above identity, we show both sides of (1) satisfy the same non-homogeneous recurrence $x(s+1)-v^2x(s)=\binom{2s}{s+1}\frac{(v-1)^{s+1}}s$ and just check one initial condition, say at $s=1$.

Suppressing other variables, let $F_1(s,k)=\binom{s+k-1}k\frac{s-k}sv^{s-1-k}(v-1)^k$ and $F_2(s,k)=\binom{2s}k\frac{s-k}s(v-1)^k$. The above method generates the **WZ-mates** 
\begin{align} G_1(s,k)&=F_1(s,k)
\frac{v^2(s+2-k)k}{(s-k)(s+1)}, \\
G_2(s,k)&=F_2(s,k)
\frac{(2s^2v+4sv+2s^2+3s-3svk-3kv+2v-2sk+vk^2)k}{(2s-k+1)(2s+2-k)(s-k)}
\end{align}
satisfying the relations (check using a computer)
\begin{align}
F_1(s+1,k)-v^2F_1(s,k)&=G_1(s,k+1)-G_1(s,k), \\
F_2(s+1,k)-v^2F_2(s,k)&=G_2(s,k+1)-G_2(s,k). \tag2
\end{align}
Denote $a(s)=\sum_{k=0}^{s-1}F_1(s,k)$ and $b(s)=\sum_{k=0}^{s-1}F_2(s,k)$.
Now, sum both equations in (2) over integers $0\leq k\leq s$. For instance, the first equation in (2) gives
$$a(s+1)-v^2a(s)-v^2F_1(s,s)=G_1(s,s+1)-G_1(s,0).$$ 
But, $F_1(s,s)=0=G_1(s,0)$ and hence $a(s+1)-v^2a(s)=G_1(s,s+1)$.

Similarly, the second equation in (2) leads to
$$b(s+1)-v^2b(s)-v^2F_2(s,s)=G_2(s,s+1)-G_2(s,0).$$ 
But, $F_2(s,s)=0=G_2(s,0)$ and hence $b(s+1)-v^2b(s)=G_2(s,s+1)$.

However, after some algebraic simplification, we obtain
$$G_1(s,s+1)=G_2(s,s+1)=\binom{2s}{s+1}\frac{(v-1)^{s+1}}s.$$ 
Since $a(1)=b(1)$, it follows that $a(s)=b(s)$. The proof is complete.

Comment: Where does the recurrence $x(s+1)−v^2*x(s)=0$ comes from?

Comment: This too is what Zeilberger's algorithm does spit out.

Comment: I'm missing something.  For $s=1,2,3$ the sums are $v$, $2v^2-v$, $5v^3-6v^2+2v$.  Where is the recurrence $a(s+1)-v^2a(s)=0$?

Comment: We sum $a(s)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^s$ and $b(s)=\sum_{k=0}^{2s}$ and split each into two parts (one we want and the other not what we want) and each of the 2 pairs are equal. The recurrences apply to the total sum, that is why you are getting the discrepancies.

Comment: It seems the recurrence relation is not x(s+1)−v^2x(s)=0

Comment: See my comment above.

Comment: Zeilberger's algorithm in Maple returns $v^2 x(s)+x(s+2)+(-3*v+1)*x(s+1) = 0$

Comment: @LuHell: Try downloading and run it on Maple, the instructions are there: http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~zeilberg/tokhniot/EKHAD

Comment: @LuHell: I have written more details, in my answer above, to help you understand my arguments. You may easily check the computations with the above Maple package and symbolic simplifications.

Answer (score 7):

This is not an answer but just some hints.  Define $A(s)$ to be the quantity on the left and $B(s)$ to be the quantity on the right.  Define $A(0)=B(0)=1$.  Then it suffices to prove that
$$ \sum_{s\ge0} A(s)x^s = \sum_{s\ge0} B(s)x^s =
    \frac{v-2-v\sqrt{1-4(v-1)x}}{2(v^2x-1)}.$$
Another way to prove it is to show that both $A(s)$ and $B(s)$ count the closed walks of length $2s$ in an infinite regular tree of degree $v$, which is the original application.

Comment: I am very interested on how to count the closed walks and get B(s). I see you counted it to get A(s) in the proof. In fact, I am trying to derive an expression for a different regular graph model and I will need to get some similar asymptotic expression as in Lemma 3.1. I am not sure if I could prove Lemma 3.1 using A(s), so I am trying to derive B(s) in the hope to apply a similar technique to my particular graph model.
How could I count those paths?